# Using Objective C++ for WatchKit

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, objective-c++, watchkit

When I try to use Objective C++ for my WatchKit Extension, I get linker errors with messages like

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_WKInterfaceController", referenced from:
```

I tried creating a new project using the Single View Application template and then added a simple WatchKit App target to that.  Without changing anything, the whole thing compiles fine but if I rename the InterfaceController.m file to InterfaceController.mm, then even that simple project gives the above error.

How can I build a WatchKit App Extension using Objective C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find anything on the web or in Apple's dev forums on this, but I finally worked out what's going on and came up with a workaround.

The problem seems to be that some sort of magic trigger for the linker isn't happening if ALL of the source files are in C++ and Objective C++.  The solution was to create a single .m file which includes the WatchKit header.  This file only needs this for its contents:

```
#import <WatchKit/WatchKit.h>
```

Save that into a .m file, add it to the project and everything will be sunshine and rainbows.

I reported this to Apple through Radar and got this response:

> This issue behaves as intended based on the following:
>
> The difference between the objc and objc++ compiles comes down to objc
>   enabling -fmodules and objc++ not. If you build the objc without
>   -fmodules you get the same link error, and the driver is dropping -fmodules when in C++ mode, leading to the error.
>
> Looks like we get a number of linker option load commands in the
>   object when we use -fmodules, but we don't get them without. Thus, an
>   object with -fmodules can find all of the frameworks it needs on its
>   own, but an object without cannot.
>
> So the problem is simply that objective c++ modules aren't supported,
>   so the project has gone from using modules to not using modules. This
>   means autolinking isn't available, so the project needs to explicitly
>   link against the frameworks that it uses.

Comment: You will also need to explicitly link against the WatchKit framework

Answer (score 1):

For me this started happening if I set `Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)` to `NO` in the Build Settings tab of the WatchKit Extension target. Setting it back to `YES` gets rid of these errors.

Comment: Yeah, according to Apple's Radar response (see my edited answer), it's the fmodules flag, which I assume is what "Enable Modules" is affecting.  Looks like the problem is that it doesn't work for ObjC++, only C and ObjC.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my Swift project after integrating a third party framework that was written in Objective C. I had to create Bridging-Header and after that the same error message appeared because that framework was referencing WatchKit. All I had to do was importing WatchKit in the Bridging-Header:

```
#import <WatchKit/WatchKit.h>
```